# In C, not using 'void' if a function does not accept any argument is a potential vulnerability

Tags: c, secure-coding

In CERT secure coding standard, there is a recommendation that "[Always specify void even if a function accepts no arguments](https://www.securecoding.cert.org/confluence/display/seccode/DCL20-C.+Always+specify+void+even+if+a+function+accepts+no+arguments)". A possible security vulnerability is proposed in it.

```
/* Compile using gcc4.3.3 */
   void foo() {
        /* Use asm code to retrieve i
         * implicitly from caller
         * and transfer it to a less privileged file */
       }

   /* Caller */
   foo(i); /* i is fed from user input */
```

> In this noncompliant code example, a user with high privileges feeds
>   some secret input to the caller that the caller then passes to foo().
>   Because of the way foo() is defined, we might assume there is no way
>   for foo() to retrieve information from the caller. However, because
>   the value of i is really passed into a stack (before the return
>   address of the caller), a malicious programmer can change the internal
>   implementation and copy the value manually into a less privileged
>   file.

Is there any exploit which uses this "un-secure" coding practice. If not can someone explain or give a sample code how this can be used. Also, if this is really hard to exploit or not possible, could you please explain why?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

What happens here is that the `foo()` function uses a so-called *old-style declaration*, i.e. as things were done in C before the first normalization (aka "ANSI C" from 1989). In pre-ANSI C, a function `bar()` which takes two arguments of types `int` and `char *` would be *defined* that way:

```
void bar()
    int i;
    char *p;
{
    /* do some stuff */
}
```

and it would be *declared* the following way (usually in a header file):

```
void bar();
```

This means that code which uses the function would include the header file, which would then convey information about the existence of the function, and about its return type (here, `void`), but nothing whatsoever about the number of arguments and their types. Thus, upon usage, the caller must provide the parameters *and hope that it sent the appropriate number and types*. If the caller code does not do things properly, then the compiler will not emit warnings.

**As a security vulnerability**, it is not very convincing. It makes sense only in a context of code inspection. Some auditor is reviewing a lot of source code. An evil developer is trying to do evil things which the auditor will not notice (this is the scenario which is explored in the [Underhanded C Contest](http://underhanded.xcott.com/)). Presumably, the auditor will look at the header files and also at the *start* of the function implementation. In your example, he will see:

```
void foo()
{
    /* some stuff */
}
```

then the auditor may just assume that `foo()` takes no parameter, since the opening brace immediately follows the `foo()`. However, the caller code (which is elsewhere) calls `foo()` with some parameters. The C compiler cannot warn: since the function is declared "old-style", the C compiler does not know, when compiling the caller code, that `foo()` does not actually use any parameter (or so it seems). The caller code *will* push the arguments on the stack (and remove them upon return). The evil programmer then includes in the definition of `foo()` some handmade assembly to retrieve the arguments from the stack, even if, at the C syntax level, they don't exist.

Thus, a semi-hidden communication channel between two evil codes (the caller code and the called function), in a way which is not visible from a cursory inspection of the function declaration and start of definition, and, crucially, not warned upon by the C compiler either.

As a *vulnerability*, I find it pretty weak. The scenario is quite implausible.

**The issue is more about quality assurance.** Old-style declarations are *dangerous*, not because of evil programmers, but because of *human* programmers, who cannot think of everything and *must* be helped by compiler warnings. That's all the point of *function prototypes*, introduced in ANSI C, which include type information for the function parameters. In our examples, here are two prototypes:

```
void foo(void);
void bar(int, char *);
```

With these declarations, the C compiler will notice that the caller code is trying to send parameters to a function which does not use any, and will abort compilation or at least emit a sternly worded warning.

A typical problem with old-style prototypes is failure to do automatic type casts. For instance, with this function:

```
void qux()
    char *p;
    int i;
{
    /* some stuff */
}
```

and this call:

```
qux(0, 42);
```

The compiler, seeing the call, will believe that the two parameters are two `int` values. But the function really expects a *pointer* and then an `int`. If the architecture is such that a pointer takes the same size on the stack as an `int` (and also such that a NULL pointer is encoded the same way as an integer of value 0, which is a rather common feature), then things appear to work. Then compile that on an architecture where pointers are twice larger than integers: the code will fail because the `42` will be interpreted as part of the pointer value.

(The details depend on the architecture, but this would be typical of 16-bit C code compiled on a 16/32-bit architecture with 16-bit alignment, e.g. a 68000 CPU. On 64-bit modern architectures, `int` values tend to be 64-bit aligned on the stack, which saves the skin of many careless programmers. The problem is more general, though; similar issues occur with floating-point types.)

**You should use prototypes; not because old-style functions induce vulnerabilities, but because they induce *bugs*.**

Side note: in C++, prototypes are mandatory, so the `void foo();` declaration actually means "no argument whatsoever", like what `void foo(void);` would mean in ANSI C.

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong, specifying C99 standard during compiling code in GCC, this case can be prevented to occur.

Comment: you can go back to the non-safe version if you declared with `...` and use the VARARG macros to populate the parameters

Comment: In C99, old-style declarations and definition are an "obsolescent feature" but still supported (see section 6.11.6 and 6.11.7 of the C standard). GCC goes "out of his way" to actually abort compilation when in "C99 mode", which means that GCC's C99 mode is _not_ conforming to C99 -- but I agree that GCC's behaviour makes a lot of sense, and we cannot blame it for being a bit proactive.

Answer (score 5):

In C, the function prototype `foo();` declares a function which takes an unspecified number of parameters. This differs from many other languages (including C++) in which such a prototype would indicate a function that takes *no* parameters.

The two potential problems listed on the page you link to are given as **Ambiguous Interface** and **Information Outflow**.

Starting with the latter, one might imagine working for an organisation that handles classified information. Code audits could be performed to ensure that TOP SECRET information cannot flow into a file that is classified as only SECRET. Such a code audit could easily miss a prototype like `foo();`, which would actually allow information to flow into it in the form of an undeclared parameter. If `foo();` is something like `update_log();` and our double-agent is able to alter the code for `update_log();` to receive a parameter and write it as a log entry, you might see how outflow can be achieved.

The other potential issue, ambiguous interface, refers to the fact that the prototype `foo();` can be called in different ways. It's a little far-fetched, but not impossible, that such ambiguity could lead to a software vulnerability.

If an implementation of foo(); is doing something very non-standard such as using pointer arithmetic to reach into it's callers stack frame, then passing parameters to `foo();` would break that pointer arithmetic leading to arbitrary problems.